# VBScript Multiple folder check if then statement

Tags: vbscript

I had this working before just fine with the exception of getting an error if one of the folders was not there, so I tried to fix it. Searched for a while (as much as I can at work) for a solution and tried different methods, still no luck and my IT tickets are stacking up at work, lol, woohoo. Thanks for any help provided. Getting syntax error on line 60 character 60, thanks again.

```
Option Explicit 
Dim objFSO, Folder1, Folder2, Folder3, zipFile
Dim ShellApp, zip, oFile, CurDate, MacAdd, objWMIService
Dim MyTarget, MyHex, MyBinary, i, strComputer, objItem, FormatMAC
Dim oShell, oCTF, CurDir, scriptPath, oRegEx, colItems
Dim FoldPath1, FoldPath2, FoldPath3, foldPathArray
Const FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = 256

'Grabs MAC from current machine
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")
For Each objItem in colItems
    MacAdd = objItem.MACAddress
Next

'Finds the pattern of a MAC address then changes it for
'file naming purposes. You can change the FormatMAC line of the code
'in parenthesis where the periods are, to whatever you like
'as long as its within the standard file naming convention
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
oRegEx.Pattern = "([\dA-F]{2}).?([\dA-F]{2}).?([\dA-F]" _
& "{2}).?([\dA-F]{2}).?([\dA-F]{2}).?([\dA-F]{2})"
FormatMAC = oRegEx.Replace(MacAdd, "$1.$2.$3.$4.$5.$6")

'Gets current date in a format for file naming
'Periods can be replaced with anything that is standard to
'file naming convention
CurDate = Month(Date) & "." & Day(Date) & "." & Year(Date)

'Gets path of the directory where the script is being ran from
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
scriptPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set oFile = objFSO.GetFile(scriptPath)
CurDir = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(oFile)

'where and what the zip file will be called/saved
MyTarget = CurDir & "\" & "IRAP_LOGS_" & CurDate & "_" & FormatMAC & ".zip"

'Actual creation of the zip file
MyHex = Array(80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0)
For i = 0 To UBound(MyHex)
    MyBinary = MyBinary & Chr(MyHex(i))
Next
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oCTF = objFSO.CreateTextFile(MyTarget, True)
oCTF.Write MyBinary
oCTF.Close
Set oCTF = Nothing
wScript.Sleep(3000)

folder1 = True
folder2 = True
folder3 = True

'Adds folders to the zip file created earlier
'change these folders to whatever is needing to be copied into the zip folder
'Folder1
If not objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog") and If not objFSO.FolderExists("X:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog") then
    Folder1 = false
End If

If objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog") Then
    Folder1 = "C:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog"
    Set FoldPath1 = objFSO.getFolder(Folder1)
Else
    Folder1 = "X:\windows\Temp\SMSTSLog"
    Set FoldPath1 = objFSO.getFolder(Folder1)
End If

'Folder2
    If not objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs") and If not objFSO.FolderExists("X:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs") then
    Folder2 = false
End If
If objFSO.FolderEXists("C:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs") Then
    Folder2 = "C:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs"
    Set FoldPath2 = objFSO.getFolder(Folder2)
Else
    Folder2 = "X:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs"
    Set FoldPath2 = objFSO.getFolder(Folder2)
End If
'Folder3
If not objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs") and If not objFSO.FolderExists("X:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs") then
    Folder3 = false
End If
If objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs") Then
    Folder3 = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs"
    set FolderPath3 =objFSO.getFolder(Folder3)
Else
    Folder3 = "X:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs"
    Set FoldPath3 = objFSO.getFolder(Folder3)
End If

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.OpenTextFile(MyTarget, 2, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) _
& String(18, Chr(0))

Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set zip = ShellApp.NameSpace(MyTarget)





'checks if files are there before trying to copy
'otherwise it will error out
If folder1 = True And FoldPath1.files.Count >= 1 Then
    zip.CopyHere Folder1
End If
WScript.Sleep 3000
If folder2 = true And FoldPath2.files.Count >= 1 Then
     zip.CopyHere Folder2
End If
WScript.Sleep 3000
If folder3 = true And FoldPath3.files.Count >= 1 Then
     zip.CopyHere Folder3
End If


WScript.Sleep 5000

set ShellApp = Nothing
set ZipFile = Nothing
Set Folder1 = Nothing
Set Folder2 = Nothing
Set Folder3 = Nothing

createobject("wscript.shell").popup "Zip File Created Successfully", 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think*. line 60 is:

```
If not objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog") and If not objFSO.FolderExists("X:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog") then
```

A conjunctional condition should look like:

```
If somecondition And othercondition Then
```

So remove the second/embedded "If".

Comment: Thank you, I will hopefully have time to try this out in a bit and let you know, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could change those blocks with this logic `Not A And Not B` equals `Not (A Or B)`:

```
Folder1 = Not (objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog") Or _
    objFSO.FolderExists("X:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog"))

Folder2 = Not (objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs") Or _
    objFSO.FolderExists("X:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs"))

Folder3 = Not (objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs") Or _
    objFSO.FolderExists("X:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs"))
```

Also you have `Set FolderPath3 = objFSO.getFolder(Folder3)` which `FolderPath3` is not used later. It should be `Set FoldPath3 = objFSO.getFolder(Folder3)`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to find some time in a bit to try this out.